# Execute cmdlet through variable?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I want to use an `if \ else` statement to determine which cmdlet to run while keeping the same params for both commands:

For example I have this call:

```
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
        -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
        -TemplateFile $TemplateUri `
        -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParamFile
```

But I want to use a variable to determine the verb:

```
    $myVerb = if ($booleanTest) {"Test"} else {"New"}
    [$myVerb]-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment `
         -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
         -TemplateFile $TemplateUri `
         -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParamFile
```

OR something like this:

```
    $command = if ($booleanTest) {"Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment"} else {"New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment"}
    $command `
         -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
         -TemplateFile $TemplateUri `
         -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParamFile
```

I tried the `$command` version but it failed with this:

> At
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\projects\deloitte\Suncore\Dev\scripts\az-d
>   eploy.ps1:36 char:13
>   +             -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup 
>   `+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Unexpected token '-ResourceGroupName' in expression or statement. At
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Dropbox\projects\deloitte\Suncore\Dev\scripts\az-d
>   eploy.ps1:36 char:32
>   +             -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup`
>   +                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do exactly what you are describing you'd need to wrap the whole command as a string and then call it with `Invoke-Expression`. For Example:

```
$MyCommand = "$myVerb-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -TemplateFile $TemplateUri"
Invoke-Expression $MyCommand
```

But I think this isn't a very clear way to write a script. A better option would be to use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1), which is where you create a hashtable of the parameters that you can then send the cmdlet via a special `@` character with the variable name. For example:

```
$AzureParams = @{ 
    ResourceGroupName = $ResourceGroup
    TemplateFile = $TemplateUri
    TemplateParameterFile = $TemplateParamFile 
}

If ($booleanTest) {
    Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment @AzureParams
} Else {
    New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment @AzurParams
}
```

This also has the benefit of avoiding using the backtick character, which is generally encouraged as it's hard to spot and easy to break.

Comment: Splatting is definitely the way to go here

Comment: Yea, I didn't even know about it, it's such an awesome way to give cmdlets parameters. Can't imagine going back to the traditional way.

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend using this over the other answer but to directly answer your question, add the invocation operator `&`

```
$command = if ($booleanTest) {
    "Test-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment"
} else {
    "New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment"
}

& $command `
     -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
     -TemplateFile $TemplateUri `
     -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParamFile
```

Comment: Oh so it is possible, good to know. I definitely like the splatting approach but it's good to know what I was asking is actually possible as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To *complement* the existing helpful answers:

- **`Invoke-Expression` should always be the *last* resort** and is not needed here. With `Invoke-Expression`, it is tricky to get the quoting right, and its use can be a security risk (execution of arbitrary commands passed as a string, analogous to `eval` in POSIX-like shells).
- **Splatting** ([`Get-Help about_Splatting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1)) is always worth considering:

  - it is a **more robust alternative to multi-line parameter-passing** with line continuations, as [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47483600/45375) explains.
  - it **allows incremental, conditional construction of the set of parameter values** as well as their **use in multiple invocations**.
- In the case at hand, however, since **only the *command name* is variable**, [Patrick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47486739/45375) based on **`&`, the call operator** is simplest (see [`Get-Help about_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1)).

---

Generally, **you need `&` whenever the command name is *not* an *unquoted literal*** (e.g., `notepad foo.txt` works, but `'notepad' foo.txt` doesn't).

To put it differently: **you need `&`**, if your **command name** is:

- in **quotes** (whether `'...'` or `"..."`); e.g., `'notepad'`
- or is a **variable reference**; e.g., `$cmdName`
- or is the **result of an *expression*** (e.g., `('get' + '-item')`

`&` is needed in theses case in order to tell PowerShell that your intent is to invoke a *command* as opposed to evaluating an *expression*; without `&`, such tokens would be interpreted as starting an *expression*; see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-5.1) to learn about **PowerShell's two fundamental parsing modes, *argument mode* and *expression mode***.

---

While it may not be the most readable solution, you can therefore even combine an expandable string with an embedded subexpression (`$(...)` - again, see `Get-Help about_Operators`) to get away without the need for an aux. variable:

```
& "$( if ($booleanTest) {'Test'} else {'New'} )-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment" `
     -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
     -TemplateFile $TemplateUri `
     -TemplateParameterFile $TemplateParamFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) as suggested by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen):

```
Function Do-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment ([ValidateSet("Test", "New")]$Verb, $ResourceGroupName, $TemplateFile, $TemplateParameterFile) {
    $PSBoundParameters.Remove("Verb")
    & "$Verb-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment" @PSBoundParameters 
}
```